# Ionic and Allmighty Autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Has anyone been successfully able to use the Allmighty Autocomplete in their ionic app?

https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete

Below is the use case I am trying to solve for:

I have a form where I am asking the user to select their country and then based on that the cities selection will be offered.  Since there are 195 countries, the Select option is not a very realistic option.  I have looked at the several autocomplete solutions for ionic as well as angularjs.  Most of them have a search box with filter set up.  This also includes https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete

Allmighty Autocomplete is the closet one i came to but it doesn't work.  I see {{attrs.placeholder}} but when i start typing it doesn't do anything.

Comment: you actually see the expression? i.e. you see the `{{ }}` on the page? that is an indication that angular didn't load correctly; what errors are in the console?

Comment: Claies - Thank you for your help.  You are correct.  It was not loading correctly because the example it self on the github didn't have the factory.  However, the example app source code had a factory that needed to be loaded.  Now I can modify my code to make it work with a webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try with this**

1. Install bower: `npm install -g bower`
2. Then, run this on the project root: `bower install ionic-autocomplete`
3. Add this attribute on the view `<input type="text" ng-model="search" ionic-autocomplet="{item:myItems, onSelect: doSomthing}" />`
4. And finally, add this to your controller:

> ```
> .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
>    $scope.doSomthing = function(item) {
>       console.log('The selected item is: '+item);
>    }
>  });
> ```

Reference : [Bower library](https://libraries.io/bower/ionic-autocomplete)

Example : [Github](https://github.com/sn0opr/ionic-autocomplete)

*I hope this helps*

Answer (score 0):

The github example source code has a factory that needed to be loaded.